# rails 4 syntax changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I rewrite this below code with rails 4 new syntax.

```
Tracker.find(:all, :joins => :projects,
                         :select => "DISTINCT #{Tracker.table_name}.*",
                         :conditions => ["#{Project.table_name}.lft >= ? AND #{Project.table_name}.rgt <= ? AND #{Project.table_name}.status <> #{STATUS_ARCHIVED}", lft, rgt],
                         :order => "#{Tracker.table_name}.position")
```

Comment: You can use `where`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the equivalent way :

```
Tracker.joins(:projects)
       .where("#{Project.table_name}.lft >= ? AND #{Project.table_name}.rgt <= ? AND #{Project.table_name}.status <> #{STATUS_ARCHIVED}", lft, rgt)
       .select("DISTINCT #{Tracker.table_name}.*")
       .order("#{Tracker.table_name}.position")
```

Comment: Perfect!. Thanks for the code. I'll practice this new syntax!.